# can you provide two levels for the same package

Tags: logback, logback-groovy

can we able to set ERROR and INFO level at appender level?.

I am using logback.xml

my logback.xml

```
    <configuration>
        <appender name="stdout" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
            <encoder>
                <pattern>%5p [%t] %m%n</pattern>
            </encoder>
            <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
                <level>DEBUG</level>
            </filter>
        </appender>
        <appender name="default-out" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender"> <!-- Rolling file appender for rolling files -->
            <param name="File" value="logs/app-track-log.log" />
            <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
                <!-- daily rollover -->
                <fileNamePattern>logs/app-track-log-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>

                <!-- keep 30 days' worth of history -->
                <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
            </rollingPolicy>
            <param name="encoding" value="UTF-8" />
            <encoder>
                <pattern>%-30([web] %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread]) %-5level %logger{32} - %msg%n</pattern>
            </encoder>
        </appender>

        <appender name="error-out" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender"> <!-- Rolling file appender for rolling files -->
            <param name="File" value="logs/error/app-error.log" />
            <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
                <!-- daily rollover -->
                <fileNamePattern>app-error.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
                <!-- keep 30 days' worth of history -->
                <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
            </rollingPolicy>
            <param name="encoding" value="UTF-8" />
            <encoder>
                <pattern>%-30([web] %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread]) %-5level %logger{32} - %msg%n</pattern>
            </encoder>
        </appender>
<!--here the logger to initiate the write operation -->
        <logger name="org.company.controllers" level="ERROR" >
            <appender-ref ref="error-out" /> 
        </logger>

    <logger name="org.company.controllers" level="INFO" >
    <appender-ref ref="default-out" /> 
    </logger>

        <root level="OFF">
            <appender-ref ref="default-out"  />
        </root>
    </configuration>
```

I get to know that appender will perform write part(output).logger will redirect it to right appender with it's property.

Here in my case I need same package to be used in different logger level(INFO/ERROR) to provide data in different file.

My goal is to write ERROR data in one file and INFO data in another file.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is levelfilter in appender, configure level filter ERROR for error-out appender shown below

```
       <appender name="error-out" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender"> <!-- Rolling file appender for rolling files -->
            <param name="File" value="logs/error/app-error.log" />
            <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
                <!-- daily rollover -->
                <fileNamePattern>app-error.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
                <!-- keep 30 days' worth of history -->
                <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
            </rollingPolicy>
            <param name="encoding" value="UTF-8" />
            <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
                <level>ERROR</level>
                <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
                <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
            </filter>
            <encoder>
                <pattern>%-30([web] %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread]) %-5level %logger{32} - %msg%n</pattern>
            </encoder>
        </appender>
```

And for info logging

```
<appender name="default-out" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender"> <!-- Rolling file appender for rolling files -->
            <param name="File" value="logs/app-track-log.log" />
            <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
                <!-- daily rollover -->
                <fileNamePattern>logs/app-track-log-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>

                <!-- keep 30 days' worth of history -->
                <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
            </rollingPolicy>
            <param name="encoding" value="UTF-8" />
            <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
                <level>INFO</level>
                <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
                <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
            </filter>
            <encoder>
                <pattern>%-30([web] %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread]) %-5level %logger{32} - %msg%n</pattern>
            </encoder>
        </appender>
```

I assume that you are looking for logging only info and error logs in two separate file else you might need to extend the filter.

Comment: In my case if i have 2 loggers with same package, latest defined in file overrides and the previous logger was not considered.

Comment: Yes this results into only accepting the declared first appender and ignoring the rest, any idea how this may be fixed?